# How to fetch all embedded document from the Mongo multiple documents using Spring Data Mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using **Spring Data Mongo** and I've almost 10,000 documents in mongoDB. I am using `Spring Boot + Spring Data Mongo` example.

I've following documents and each document has some unique and common address:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("592c7029aafef820f432c5f3"),
  "_class" : "lankydan.tutorial.mongodb.documents.Person",
  "firstName" : "John",
  "secondName" : "Doe",
  "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("2017-05-29T20:02:01.636+01:00"),
  "address" : {
    "addressLineOne" : "19 Imaginary Road",
    "addressLineTwo" : "Imaginary Place",
    "city" : "Imaginary City",
    "country" : "US"
  },
  "profession" : "Winner",
  "salary" : 100,
  "hobbies" : [ 
    {
      "name" : "Badminton"
    }, 
    {
      "name" : "TV"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since, `address` is embedded into the User collection. How to fetch all the unique address or all address? I want to write service for this.

Do I need to create indexing for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply achieved in the latest version of `Spring Boot Starter Parent` `2.1.4.RELEASE` as per [Spring Data Mongo Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.query.distinct)

```
List<Object> object = mongoTemplate.query(User.class).distinct("address").all();
for (Object object2 : object) {
    Address address = (address) object2;
    System.out.println(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a POJO class named Address in which you have to define its fields as :

```
 public class Address {

 private String addressLineOne;
 private String addressLineTwo;
 private String city;
 private String country;

// getters and setters

}
```

Then, you have to modify your User.java class :

```
public class User {

private String id;
// other fields    
private Address address;
// other fields

}
```

Spring's jackson liberary will automatically bind these fields to your POJO.

Now, when you try to get the fields of your address, you will get this by using :

```
System.out.println(user.getAddress.getAddressLineOne);
System.out.println(user.getAddress.getCity);
```

Comment: I am afraid but somewhere you have to iterate all the users for getting the addresses of all users because by concept mongoTemplate have reference to "user" document not to "address".

Comment: Aggregation selectOnlyAddress = newAggregation(project("address"));

List<Address> addresses = mongoTemplate.aggregate(selectOnlyAddress, "YourCollectionName", Address.class);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191232/discussion-between-ankush-and-paa).

Comment: Its still not working .. I dont see any result is coming

Comment: Because few of my documents contains list of Addresses as well, in that case it doesn't works

Comment: Not an issue, just use newAggregation(unwind("address"),project("address"));

Comment: This is not pulling data at all, all the fields are showing null values. Do we missed something ?